# Two Way Binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am (very) new to WPF and I have got a question regarding that. It may be a very stupid one, so please excuse me if that is the case.

I am doing a project where I am binding my textboxes, etc to static properties inside a singleton class. My problem is that the twoWay Binding is not working. When the textbox changes, I can see that the value of the property changes, but when the property changes, I can't see the textbox text changing.

To see what's going on I wrote a small app, with just the relevant code. Please find the code below.

In the code below, I am changing the text in the textbox and source property in various places and noted my observations. If someone can tell me what I am doing wrong and point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

I also tried INotifyPropertyChanged, but it gives problems because of the static property. Is there a different approach when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for a static property.

Thanks in advance,
Abhi.

**XAML:**

```
<Page x:Class="TestBindingApp.Page1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Prefs="clr-namespace:TestBindingApp"
  xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=System"
  xmlns:winForms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
  xmlns:wfi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
Title="Page1" Loaded="Page_Loaded">
<Page.Resources>
    <Prefs:Class1 x:Key="TClass"></Prefs:Class1>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15 5 5 0" Height="20">
        <TextBlock Name="txbBankNumber" Margin="50 0 0 0" Padding="2">Bank Account Number :</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Name="txtBankNumber" Margin="10 0 0 0" Width="100" MaxLength="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource TClass}" Path="AccountNumber" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnValidationError="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

**XAML.CS:**

```
namespace TestBindingApp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        txtBankNumber.Text = "ABC";
 // I can see the property AccountNumber changing here
        Class1.AccountNumber = "123456";
 // Value in txtBankNumber doesn't change here
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtBankNumber.Text = "ABCDE";
 // I can see the property AccountNumber changing here

        Class1.AccountNumber = "12345678";
 // Value in txtBankNumber doesn't change here

    }
}
```

}

**Class Class1:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestBindingApp
{
public class Class1
{
    // Singleton instance
    private static Class1 instance;
    private static string _accountNumber;
    public Class1()
    {

    }

    // Singleton instance read-only property
    public static Class1 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Class1();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public static string AccountNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _accountNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _accountNumber)
            {
                _accountNumber = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

=====================

Couldn't post my updated code in the comments, so updating my original post.

Below is my updated code, which has the "if(PropertyChanged != null)", but it gives me an error - "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TestBindingApp.Class1.NotifyPropertyChanged(string)'". .

I have just started learning WPF, so if you could explain in detail, that would be very helpful. Thanks for your patience.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestBindingApp
{
public class Class1: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Singleton instance
    private static Class1 instance;
    private static string _accountNumber;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Class1()
    {

    }

    // Singleton instance read-only property
    public static Class1 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Class1();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public static string AccountNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _accountNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _accountNumber)
            {
                _accountNumber = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("AccountNumber");
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    } 

}
```

}

==============

### ***Updated 23rd June, 09:53 AM UK time***

Hi Arcturus, I have changed the properties to non-static, but it is still not behaving as I expect it to. Am I expecting it to do something which it isn't meant to do, or am I doing something wrong. 
In the below code, I expected the textbox to show 12345678 (or maybe 123456) as the account number, but it still shows 123. In the debug mode, I can see PropertyChanged event executing correctly after each property change statement, but the value of the textbox doesn't change. Does the binding take affect only at the time of initialization (InitializeComponent()), or am I missing something here?

**Page code-behind**

```
namespace TestBindingApp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        Class1.Instance.AccountNumber = "123";
        InitializeComponent();
        Class1.Instance.AccountNumber = "123456";
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Class1.Instance.AccountNumber = "12345678";
    }
}
}
```

**Class1.cs**

```
namespace TestBindingApp
{
public class Class1: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Singleton instance
    private static Class1 instance;
    private static string _accountNumber;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public Class1()
    {

    }

    // Singleton instance read-only property
    public static Class1 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Class1();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public string AccountNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _accountNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _accountNumber)
            {
                _accountNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AccountNumber");
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    } 

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need the INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestBindingApp
{
public class Class1
{
    // Singleton instance
    private static Class1 instance;
    private string _accountNumber;
    public Class1()
    {

    }

    // Singleton instance read-only property
    public static Class1 Instance
    {
    get
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
        instance = new Class1();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    }

    public string AccountNumber
    {
    get
    {
        return _accountNumber;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _accountNumber)
        {
        _accountNumber = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AccountNumber");
        }
    }
    }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this approach before, but it gives me an error - "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TestBindingApp.Class1.NotifyPropertyChanged(string)'". 

Looks like it is because of the static class. Is there a different way to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for a staic property?

Comment: Please note the if(PropertyChanged != null) in NotifyPropertyChanged.. Its there for a reason ;)

Comment: Sorry Arcturus, I didn't get your meaning. Couldn't post my updated code in the comments, so updated my original post.

My updated code has the "if(PropertyChanged != null)", but it gives me an error - "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TestBindingApp.Class1.NotifyPropertyChanged(string)'". . 

I have just started learning WPF, so if you could explain in detail, that would be very helpful. Thanks for your patience.

Thanks, Abhi.

Comment: Also, I prefer to set the PropertyChanged to an empty delegate to start with - then I never have to worry about null checks:

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

Comment: If I give "txtBankNumber.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();" after changing value of AccountNumber property, the textbox property changes fine. That means that the binding is setup properly, but the NotifyPropertyChanged event is not working properly because of something that I need to do. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you make both your field and property non static ?

Comment: Nope, I didn't changed them to non-static as there are a few fields that I have to keep static. I am looking for a way to accomplish twoWay binding with static properties. I can do that with updating target from the code-behind using "txtBankNumber.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget()", but thats not ideal and it would be same as manually setting the text property of the textbox.

Comment: I dont see why the property needs to be static, when you can access them through the Instance as well.. In stead of Class1.AccountNumber, you can also do Class1.Instance.AccountNumber when the property is non static.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't thought of that, my bad!! I will try that. Thanks a lot Arcturus.

Comment: Hi Arcturus, I have updated my original post with my latest code. It is still not behaving as I expect it to. Am I expecting it to do something which it isn't meant to do, or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: also change your field to non static: private static string _accountNumber; should be private string _accountNumber;

Comment: I tried that, but when I changed it to non-static the value in the textbox never changed. It shows up as blanks on the page.

Comment: Your binding needs to change as well:

<Binding Source="{StaticResource TClass}" Path="Instance.AccountNumber" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnValidationError="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">

Answer (score 0):

You call NotifyPropertyChanged from a static member, but NotifyPropertyChanged itself isn't static.

Two ways to solve: Either make AccountNumber NOT static or provide an instance for your call to NotifyPropertyChanged (e.g. "Instance.NotifyPropertyChanged(...)")

Comment: I can't change the property to non-static because that will not serve it's purpose. I changed NotifyPropertyChanged("AccountNumber") to Instance.NotifyPropertyChanged("AccountNumber"). 
The application builds fine, but it still doesn't work. When it goes inside the NotifyPropertyChanged method, PropertyChanged is null and it doesn't change the textbox value.  Any ideas?

Comment: If I give "txtBankNumber.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();" after changing value of AccountNumber property, the textbox property changes fine. That means that the binding is setup properly, but the NotifyPropertyChanged event is not working properly because of something that I need to do. Any other ideas?